# Identification of garden insect with a red-edged green body and white spots

Tags: insects

Please can someone Identify this New Zealand Bug found on my lawn today, thank you.

[image: beetle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is a Green vegatable bug (Nezara viridula, a.k.a. southern green stink bug) in one of its juvenile forms (nymph I believe). Here are a couple of examples:
 [image: Example 1] [image: Example 2]

There are a number of stages of growth so the adult beetle looks quite different from this one.

This beetle is a recognized pest of citrus plants and legumes (among others) and will often feed on developing shoots and fruits so I would keep a look out for others. The eggs will be laid in clusters and the newly hatched bugs will be black and feed in groups. The adult should have a shield-bug shape and be green to reddish brown.

Example:
[image]